# Is "stackiness" transitive? (and a couple other basic questions about stacks)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Say, $B$ is a category fibered in groupoids over some category $C$, and $A$ is a category fibered in groupoids over $B$.

Suppose $A$ is a stack (over whatever site) over $B$, and $B$ is a stack over $C$, is $A$ also a stack over $C$?

"Conversely", if $A$ is a stack over $C$ and $B$ is a stack over $C$, then must $A$ be a stack over $B$?

Also, do properties like being algebraic, having a coarse moduli space, etc, depend on what you consider the base category to be? (Ie, if $A$ as a stack over $B$ is algebraic/has a CMS, then must $A$ as a stack over $C$ be algebraic/have a CMS as well?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I think the first and second question are not sufficiently precise. I am going to assume you mean: C is a site and B is endowed with the [topology inherited from C](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06NV). In this case the Stacks project contains a lemma stating that the answer to your second question is "yes". See [Lemma Tag 06NX](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06NX).

Strangely, the statement that the composition A --> B --> C turns A into a fibred category over C if A --> B and B --> C define fibred categories (and similarly for categories fibred in groupoids and for stacks with topologies as above) seems to be missing from the Stacks project. I believe these are true, easier to prove than the lemma above, and they should be added there ([now done](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/commit/c2d70d98ac03558cdfdf5921378ff7370ffaab54)).

An example of a statement of the kind you seem to be asking for in your final paragraph, in the setting of algebraic stacks, is [Lemma Tag 05XY](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05XY). Enjoy!

Comment: Purely for completeness: the stacks project is at http://stacks.math.columbia.edu.